# Need help fixing code to output correct unique word count from a file

Tags: c++, arrays, string, word-count

I am trying to find the unique word count from a text file. But for some reason, my number is always off. My regular word count comes out fine though.

My string Array `wordArr` contains all the words from the file.

I try assigning every word to another array after it is found to be not unique, then I go through the list of words that I have already been through to see if it matches the current word being shown. If the words match I set `oldWord` to true and the word is not counted toward my `unique` count.

```
//New portion
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //File Paths
    ifstream fp;
    fp.open(argv[1]);
    if (fp.fail()) {
        cout << "Error No file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    string wordArr[10000];
    string words;
    string temp;
    int wordCount = 0;


    while (fp >> words) {
        int newWord = 0;
        for (int i; i < words.length(); i++) {
            if (isalpha(words[i])) {

            } else {
                wordArr[wordCount++] = words.substr(0, i);
                //wordCount++;
                newWord = 1;
                if(words[i] + 1 != '\0') {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j <  words.length(); j++) {
                        temp = temp +words[j];
                    }
                    wordArr[wordCount++] = temp;
                    //wordCount++;
                }

            }

        }
        if (newWord == 0) {
            wordArr[wordCount] = words;
            wordCount++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Number of words found was: " << wordCount << endl;
    //New portion


    // makes all lower
    for(int k=0; k<wordCount;k++){ //need to find size of array
        for(int l=0; l<wordArr[k].length(); l++){
            tolower(wordArr[k].at(l));
        }

    }



    //unique count
    string tempArr[10000];
    int unique=0;
    int oldWord=0;
    for(int m=0; m<wordCount;m++ ) {
        for (int n = 0; n < wordCount; n++) {
            if (wordArr[m] == tempArr[n]) {


                oldWord = 1;
            }
        }
        if(oldWord==0){
            wordArr[m] = tempArr[n];
            unique++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Unique word count is: " << unique << endl;
}
```

I expect to get 52 unique words from my test case, but end up only getting 37.

Test case:

> Cryptography is both the practice and study of the techniques used to
>   communicate and/or store information or data privately and
>   securely, without being intercepted by third parties. This can include
>   processes such as encryption, hashing, and steganography. Until the
>   modern era, cryptography almost exclusively referred to encryption, but
>   now cryptography is a broad field with applications in many critical
>   areas of our lives.

Comment: If you must use an array container, prefer `std::vector`, as it can expand dynamically during run-time.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ transform string tolower".

Comment: This would be much easier with a `std::(unordered_)map` to track the unique words for you, eg: `map<string, int> unique; for(int m = 0; m < wordCount; ++m) { unique[wordArr[m]]++; } cout << "Unique word count is: " << unique.size() << endl;` or a `set::(unordered_)set` instead if you don't care about tracking how many times each word repeats:  `set<string> unique; for(int m = 0; m < wordCount; ++m) { unique.insert(wordArr[m]); } cout << "Unique word count is: " << unique.size() << endl;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried using the map idea you suggested and I end up getting 55 instead, but the correct unique word count is 52. I'm not sure how maps work exactly so i'm not sure if this has to do with the map, or with the way I set lowercase. Any Ideas?

Comment: Nathan, What Remy suggested should work. Can you add your version with `map` at the bottom of the question?

Comment: @NathanBarry Then there is a problem with how you are parsing words into `wordArr` (but you did not show that code). In the sample text you provided, I count (ignoring case and punctuation) 64 total words, and 52 unique words. How many words is your code putting into `wordArr`? Please provide a [mcve] that shows exactly how you are processing the sample text and reproduces the issue in action.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have updated my post to include to how I can in all the words from the file, ignoring punctuation and anything that isn't a letter. Any help is greatly appreciated. I apologize for not including it earlier.

Comment: @NathanBarry As suspected, your parsing code has faulty logic (in fact, it doesn't even compile). There are logic errors in how you break up words on non-alpha characters, in how you look for and track duplicate words, and even in how you are lower-casting words. In short, this entire code is full of bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parsing code has faulty logic (in fact, it doesn't even compile).  There are logic errors in how you break up words on non-alpha characters, in how you look for and track duplicate words, and even in how you are lower-casting words.

In short, this entire code is full of bugs that need to be fixed, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //File Paths
    ifstream fp;
    fp.open(argv[1]);
    if (!fp.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error No file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    string wordArr[10000];
    string words;
    int wordCount = 0;
    while ((fp >> words) && (wordCount < 10000)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); ++i) {
            if (!isalpha(words[i])) {
                wordArr[wordCount++] = words.substr(0, i);
                if (wordCount == 10000) break;
                ++i;
                while ((i < words.length()) && (!isalpha(words[i]))) {
                    ++i;
                }
                words.erase(0, i);
                i = -1;
            }
        }
        if (words.length() > 0) {
            wordArr[wordCount++] = words;
        }
    }
    cout << "Number of words found was: " << wordCount << endl;

    // makes all lower
    for(int k=0; k<wordCount;k++){ //need to find size of array
        for(int l=0; l<wordArr[k].length(); l++){
            wordArr[k][l] = tolower(wordArr[k][l]);
        }
    }

    //unique count
    string tempArr[10000];
    int unique=0;
    for(int m=0; m<wordCount;m++ ) {
        int oldWord=0;
        for (int n = 0; n < unique; n++) {
            if (wordArr[m] == tempArr[n]) {
                oldWord = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(oldWord==0){
            tempArr[unique++] = wordArr[m];
        }
    }
    cout << "Unique word count is: " << unique << endl;
}
```

[Now the code works as expected](https://ideone.com/Owx5hK):

```
Number of words found was: 64
Unique word count is: 52
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! And I appreciate all the time you spent to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the oldWord in each iteration:

```
 //unique count
string tempArr[10000];
int unique=0;
int oldWord=0;
for(int m=0; m<wordCount;m++ ) {
    for (int n = 0; n < wordCount; n++) {
        if (wordArr[m] == tempArr[n]) {


            oldWord = 1;
        }
    }
    if(oldWord==0){
        wordArr[m] = tempArr[n];
        unique++;
    }
    // reset the oldWord variable here
    oldWord=0;

}
cout << "Unique word count is: " << unique << endl;
```

}

Comment: When I tested this it changes the value to 63, but that is still the wrong value. The correct value being 52.